# ConfigureMapping using Parameters with multiple dots

Tags: c#, service, nservicebus

I'm facing to a problem when implementing the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga()` method of a saga orchestration service class.

in this method i have to specify how to connect the message received to the current saga conversation. I have to specify in particular the property of the message which contains the saga id. 
This propery is like this: `message.Sup.SubProperty` and i can't do it becouse the nservicebus gets just the first property of `message`.

I don't want to change my nservicebus version.

how can i figure it out?

Comment: Is it possible to push up that property?  Also, what version are you running?

Comment: my version is 2.6.0.1054. What do you mean with push up the property? if you mean to create a shortcut in the message it's impossibile becouse i don't have the control of message that arrives to my application(they all follow a business standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a message handler which sends a new kind of message that has the property with which you need to correlate defined at a higher level.
2. Write your own saga finder by implementing IFindSagas<T>.Using<M>.

I think that option 1 would be easier to code. You can also host the handler in the same endpoint as the saga and then do a Bus.SendLocal so that it doesn't impact your deployment in any significant manner.

Comment: the option number one is the one i was thinking about and probably will be the solution for this problem. Option number 2 would be better and i tried to do it but the output of FindBy method of IfindSagas.Using is a unique Saga istance and i would need multiple saga istance. Do i have to change the interface IFindSagas.Using?

Comment: Currently we don't support multiple saga instances being processed per message - we're looking at that direction in the next major release.